# EF Code First / WPF Application architecture guidance needed

Tags: wpf, caching, architecture, frameworks, entity

I'm working on a 2-tier WPF/EF Code First application. I did a lot of googling but couldn't find a sample implementation of what I was looking for... was hoping that someone on this forum could help me out. Here are the requirements:

- On Application Start up

  1. Open a DBContext
  2. Cache the reference data in various maps/lists when the application starts
  3. Close Context.
- When user opens a form

  1. Open a DBContext (I'm using UnitOfWork pattern here)
  2. Fetch a fresh copy of Entity from context for Editing.
  3. Call SaveChanges() when Save button is hit.
  4. Close the Context.

The problem manifests when I use an object from Cache to change a navigation property.
e.g. use a drop down (backed by cache which was created using a different DBContext) to set Department navigation property.

The UnitOfWork either throws an exception saying entity was loaded in another DBContext (When Department is lazy loaded DynamicProxy) or inserts a new row in Department table.

I couldn't find even a single example where reference data was being cached... I can't believe that no one came across this issue. Either I'm not looking in the right place or not using the right keywords.
I hope this is doable using EF. I'd appreciate if you can share your experiences or post some references.
I'm kinda new to this so would like to avoid using too many frameworks and just stick to POCO with WPF/EF stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up defining int foreign key property in addition to navigation.
In my application I only modify the int property and use the navigation property for displaying the details (read only controls).
While this works it makes the application a little fragile and sometimes inconsistent.

although this blog claims that the FK & Navi properties are synced by EF but I couldn't get it to work.

http://coding.abel.nu/2012/03/ef-code-first-navigation-properties-and-foreign-keys

Answer (score 1):

Try to attach your cached item (probably, you'd make a clone before attaching):

```
var existingUnicorn = GetMyExistingUnicorn();
using (var context = new UnicornsContext())
{
    context.Unicorns.Attach(existingUnicorn);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Refer to [Using DbContext...](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/29/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-4-add-attach-and-entity-states.aspx) article.

Comment: It works only if the entity is not dynamic proxy. otherwise you get an exception saying object can not be attached as it was loaded from a different db context.

Comment: well, can you detach it first?

Answer (score 0):

You mention you are using WPF for this, in that case you don't necessarily have to open a new DBContext every time you want to interact with the domain layer. (Apologies if this goes against UoW that you are keen on using)

Personally I have been using code-first development for a desktop application, and I have found that pooling the contexts (and therefore the connection) prevents this problem, and hasn't led to any problems thus far.

In principle, as soon as the application is launched, a main Context object is opened for the main UI thread, and stays open throughout the duration of the application lifetime. It is stored statically, and is retrieved by any Repository class when they are used.

For multi-threading scenarios, any background threads are free to open up additional contexts and use them in Repositories to prevent any race conditions.

If you were to adopt this approach, you would find that as all repositories share the same context, there are no issues arising from object context tracking.

Comment: how do you handle the scenario where multiple forms are open and modified, one is saved and the other one is cancelled.

Comment: Not sure I quite follow. The DBContext is pooled, and can therefore be stored as a singleton object for the UI thread to access. In the case that a form is closed, then don't call the DatabaseManager.SaveForm() method, or whatever you're wrapper class is for saving the entities.

Comment: I'm talking about the case where the entities are directly bound to the fields using xaml-binding.

Comment: Ok - it shouldn't matter what you are doing in your UI layer. Perhaps im not explaining myself well enough, but what I am trying to communicate is that if you don't open a seperate DB context for each form/ui/module etc.. and ONLY open one at the start of the application, closing when the user exists the application, you won't get exceptions relating to entities being loaded from separate contexts, as there is only one being shared throughout your application. Objects will always be in sync as they are being tracked from the same context.